# placing divs side by side and in columns

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a design which I am following to create my front end. I am having difficulty  in spacing the divs.

My design looks like:
[image]

I am trying to create the same in angular

code

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-bewteen start" fxLayoutGap="12px" class="side_start">
    <div fxFlex="12" class="second_bar">
        Side
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="88" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-bewteen" fxLayoutGap="12px">
        <div ngClass=third_bar_1>
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-bewteen start" fxLayoutGap="12px">
                <div fxFlex="8" class="zone">
                        Zone Thermal Comfort
                </div>
                <div fxFlex="5" class="temp">
                    <p>TEMP</p>
                    <p>37 deg</p>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
        <div class=third_bar_2>
            second
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.css

```
.third_bar_1{
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color: white;
    height: 60px;
}

.zone {
    /* font-color: #5d6d88; */
    background-color: #f1cd86;
    text-align: center;
    height: 71%;
}

.temp {
    background-color: #73d9fa 
}

.third_bar_2{   
    border:1px solid red;
    height: calc(100vh - 355px);
}
```

and it looks like:
[image]

how to create the divs as shown in the image with different divs horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do that using pure css that would be a bit difficult. You can do it using bootstrap which is css frmaework very easily. Just read some tutorials about bootstrap grid system you will be able to do this easily. Here is an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Grid</h1>
  <p>This example demonstrates a 50%/50% split on small, medium and large devices. On extra small devices, it will stack (100% width).</p>      
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>      
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:pink;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to align it with the desired design.

You need first write the markup keepin in mind the flexbox.

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
background-color: #efefef;
}

.menu .left {
  display: flex;
align-items: center;  
  
}

.menu .left .left-left{
  display: flex;
align-items: center;  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-left">
        <div class="first">
        <p>Zonal thermal Comfort</p>  
        </div>
        <div class="second">
          <div class="up">
            <p>Temp</p>
          </div>
          <div class="down">
            <p>37 Deg</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fourth">
          <p>48</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="left-right">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/93x45" alt="">
    </div>
 </div> 
  <div class="right">
    <p>otherstuff</p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

```html
<div class="menu">

</div>
```

Now this is a very basic implementation of flexbox. The properties that you require to implement this design are 
**align-items** : This will align you align items vertically  
**justify-content** : This will align you align items horizontally 
**flex-direction** : This will change your [main-axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#The_main_axis) from horizontal to vertical according to the value

Read flexbox in detail, in will help you develop 1-D layouts. [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)